# Insert list of class's object to Room by parsing API data using MVVM in Kotlin

Tags: android, api, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

I built an application in Kotlin using MVVM. I fetched the API response from the server successfully. Now I want to insert API's parsing data into RoomDB.

API response included both JSON Object & Array. I want to insert specific data from API to DB. Please help me with how I can make an entity class and set parsing data to the class data members with/without loops and insert it into RoomDB by making a single list of the whole class.

Please provide tutorial links or any kind of material links instead of the Android Developers Guide. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In API Response we have many data but actually, we don't need that all that so basically we to create one data class that is only constant the specific that actually, we need. and that all operation is performed in a repository and we manage it.

***entity class that only contains essential data***

```
    @Entity(tableName = "wallpaper")
data class WallpaperDataClass (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val note_id:Int=0,
    val photoId: Int,
    val photos_url: String,
    val photographer_name: String,
    val photographer_url: String,
    val src:String
)
```

**Fill the data in model**

```
      if (NetworkUtils.isOnline(applicationContext)) {
            /**
             *            Online
             *  if Your net is online then call api
             */

            try {
                val result: Response<PhotoModel> =
                    wallpaperInterface.getWallpaper(authorization, page, per_page)
                if (result.body() != null) {
                    val photos = mutableListOf<WallpaperDataClass>()
                    result.body()!!.photos.forEach {

                     // in blows line we set data in modal

                        val wallpaperDataClass = WallpaperDataClass(
                            photoId = it.id,
                            photos_url = it.url,
                            photographer_name = it.photographer,
                            photographer_url = it.photographerUrl,
                            src = it.src.portrait
                        )
                        photos.add(wallpaperDataClass)

                        if (!offlineDatabase.getDao().exists(it.id)){
                            offlineDatabase.getDao().insertWallpaper(wallpaperDataClass)
                        }
                        mutableLiveData.postValue(ErrorHandling.Success(photos))
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("WallpaperResponse", "getWallpaper: ${result.message()}")
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                mutableLiveData.postValue(ErrorHandling.Faild(e.localizedMessage!!.toString()))
            }
        } else {
            /**
             * Offline
             *if Your net is offline then fetch from db
             */
            try {
                val wallpaper = offlineDatabase.getDao().getOfflineWallpaper()
                mutableLiveData.postValue(ErrorHandling.Success(wallpaper))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                mutableLiveData.postValue(ErrorHandling.Faild(e.localizedMessage!!.toString()))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Video Tutorial